# Raspberry Pi google assiatant not working

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I am making a google assistant on my raspeberry pi. But at the end, when I type

```
(env) pi@Raspberrypi:~ $ python -m googlesamples.assistant.grpc.pushtotalk
```

It just says:

```
INFO:root:Connecting to embeddedassistant.googleapis.com
WARNING:root:Device config not found: [Errno 2] No such file or           directory: '/home/pi/.config/googlesamples-assistant/device_config.json'
INFO:root:Registering device
ERROR:root:Option --device-model-id required when registering a device     instance.
```

Comment: okay i was supposed to say googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk --project-id inner-bonus-190416 --device-model-id inner-bonus-190416 but then it says INFO:root:Connecting to embeddedassistant.googleapis.com
WARNING:root:Device config not found: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/pi/.config/googlesamples-assistant/device_config.json'
INFO:root:Registering device
ERROR:root:Failed to register device: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Could not create the device instance. Client type need to be specified as SDK_LIBRARY or SDK_SERVICE.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"

Answer (score 0):

solution: update the library, using the following command
py -m pip install --upgrade google-assistant-sdk[samples]

Apparently there was a bug in the library.
Updating the library solved the issue.

Comment: Thank you I will try that when I get home.