# error while connecting to google assistant with my raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi3, google-assistant-sdk

I'm following this tutorial here:

https://www.hackster.io/Salmanfarisvp/googlepi-google-assistant-on-raspberry-pi-9f3677

to use Google Asistant on my Raspberry Pi 3.

I got to step 4 (using the updated SDK) but I get the following output:

```
INFO:root:Connecting to embeddedassistant.googleapis.com
WARNING:root:Device config not found: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/pi/.config/googlesamples-assistant/device_config.json'
INFO:root:Registering device
ERROR:root:Option --device-model-id required when registering a device instance
```

There are some [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48167501/raspberry-pi-google-assiatant-not-working) of the same error but the solution presented there doesn't work for me (I already updated the library to the latest version)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Please follow [this step in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/embed/register-device) to register a device model.

Then you should include the `--device-model-id` parameter when you run the sample.

`googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk --project-id my-dev-project --device-model-id my-model`